# org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException while trying to access a BLOB field in entity

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jsf, primefaces

i have a lazyInitialization issue, trying to load an image (BLOB) from a mysql database into a `<p:graphicImage>` (Primefaces) using `StreamedContent` Type. i am using JSF + Spring + Hibernate and i get `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException` when i try to load an image. here is the code. thanx.

Here is the Backing Bean:

```
public class AccueilBean implements Serializable {  

    private CategorieService categorieService;
    private List<Categorie>  categories;
    private StreamedContent dbImg;        




public AccueilBean(){


}


@PostConstruct
public void init() {

    this.categories = new ArrayList<Categorie>();

    categories=categorieService.listerCategorie();

}

public List<Categorie> getCategories(){

    return this.categories;
}



public CategorieService getCategorieService() {
    return categorieService;
}


public void setCategorieService(CategorieService categorieService) {
    this.categorieService = categorieService;
}


public StreamedContent getDbImg() {

    InputStream dbStream = null;
     dbImg = null;

    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Categorie cat = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{cat}", Categorie.class);

    Long id = cat.getId();
    Categorie ctg_aux = categorieService.getCategorie(id);
    System.out.println(ctg_aux.getImage());
    try {
        dbStream = ctg_aux.getImage().getBinaryStream();
        dbImg = new DefaultStreamedContent(dbStream,"image/jpeg");
        } 
    catch (SQLException e) {System.out.println("erreur");}


    return dbImg;
}

}
```

Here is the .xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"           "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"     xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"> 

<h:head></h:head> 
<body> 
<h:form>
<p:dataGrid columns="3" var="cat" value="#{accueilBean.categories}">

<p:column>

<p:graphicImage value="#{accueilBean.dbImg}" >
</p:graphicImage>
</p:column>

</p:dataGrid>
</h:form>

</body> 
</html>
```

Here is the mapping of Categorie entity;

```
<class name="tn.projet.model.Categorie" table="CATEGORIE">
<id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
<column name="ID" />
<generator class="increment" />
</id>
<property name="nom" type="java.lang.String">
<column name="NOM" />
</property>
<property name="desc" type="java.lang.String">
<column name="DESCRIPTION" />
</property>
<property name="image" type="java.sql.Blob">
<column name="IMAGE" />
</property>
<set name="produits" table="PRODUIT" inverse="false" lazy="true">
<key>
<column name="ID" />
</key>
<one-to-many class="tn.projet.model.Produit" />
</set>
</class>
```

Comment: Can you show how the body of `CategorieService#getCategorie(id)` method looks like?

Comment: i already did it, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Categorie ctg_aux = categorieService.getCategorie(id);
```

I think with the above line, only the `ctg_aux` is load but not eagerly initialized. Meaning e.g. If you have some collection in the `Categorie`, just loading the `ctg_aux` will not load the collection. It will be lazily loaded later when actually access that collection. But the session has to be open (the entity has to be in persistent state) while access that collection. But at the point if the entity is in detached state you will see that problem.

I guess just calling `ctg_aux.getImage()` method within `categorieService.getCategorie` right after you have retrieved the entity should make hibernate load the field too.

**Update:**

In the following:

```
<property name="image" type="java.sql.Blob">
    <column name="IMAGE" />
</property>
```

Try setting `lazy="false"`:

```
<property name="image" type="java.sql.Blob" lazy="false">
    <column name="IMAGE" />
</property>
```

Comment: thx for reply, the problem is that i have an 'image' saved in database and mapped by hibernate as BLOB property, but when i load Categorie in the `datagrid` and then tried to retrieve the image i thing session is lost!! any solution for that?

Comment: You don't have access to `CategorieService#getCategorie(id)` method?

Comment: @user1108701: Or you could try using something like `@Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)` on that field in the entity.

Comment: I think it's `FetchMode` if your are using the Hibernate API.

Comment: i can retrienve other fileds like ID or NAME but BLOB image throws the org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException

Comment: Yes that's because that field is by default lazyly fetched, unlike other fields which are fetched as soon as you retreive the entity.

Comment: @user1108701: How does your entity look like?

Comment: i just added the mapping of categorie

Comment: public Categorie getCategorie(long id) {
  Categorie conf = (Categorie) getHibernateTemplate().load(Categorie.class, id);
  return conf;
 }

Comment: do u have an idea about this error: org.primefaces.application.PrimeResourceHandler handleResourceRequest
GRAVE: Error in streaming dynamic resource.